# Manipulate the java class path of an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am working on a plugin that consist of a homemade view to Eclipse.
When I run the plugin and display the classpath using  `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`
I get this as output : `D:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar`

I would like to add some .jar files for the proper functioning of my view, but I can't figure out how... I guess you can do it by adding some specifications to the MANIFEST.MF of the plugin but I don't know how to do it propely. 
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Eclipse plugin has its own classpath. To use additional jars in the plugin you need to include them in the plugin.

Add your jars to the plugin directory. Usually they are put in a 'lib' directory.

Open the plugin MANIFEST.MF editor and on the 'Runtime' tab in the 'Classpath' section click the 'Add...' button and add your jars to the class path.

On the 'Build' tab of the editor make sure the 'lib' folder is include in the Binary Build section.

Your MANIFEST.MF should end up with a `Bundle-Classpath' entry that looks something like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,
 lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,
 lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

(here I have 3 jars in a lib folder).

The build.properties file should be something like:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/,\
               lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,\
               lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,\
               lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

Comment: It is a good notation about each plugin having its own classpath.

Comment: Got it thank you, after doing so I have my .jar files well added : 
`Bundle-ClassPath: lib/archi-jar-4.77.100.jar,
 lib/daogeneration_rev1.jar,
 src/`

my build.properties is ok too, but when I test it using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` I get the same output as before: `D:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar`
It might be a problem from my test.. I will look around it.

Comment: `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` doesn't work for Eclipse plugins. Each plugin has a separate class path managed by the Eclipse OSGi code and it doesn't set that property.

Comment: Ok I understood, does there is any way to get programmatically my plugin classpath ?

Comment: I don't know of anything, a plugin classpath is a very complex thing, it isn't just a list of jars.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I've found is to create a `lib` directory in your Eclipse project (where your view is contained). Place your .jar files in said lib directory.

Then using the editor on the MANIFEST.MF, you add the .jar files to the classpath. If you wish to export the packages, you then add to the Exported Packages as well.
[image: MANFIEST.MF]

Depending upon what you are doing, you may wish/need to also update the Build Configuration.
[image: Build Configuration]

If you examine the `MANIFEST.MF` file itself, you will then see an entry for `Bundle-ClassPath`. It will list your entries. Here it has the standard "." for the project, a `resources/` directory that we export, and a couple of .jar files.

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
resources/,
lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar,
lib/apccore-client-2.11.8.jar,
lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar,
lib/ehcache-2.10.3.jar,
...
```

Note that in our experience, it is also necessary to adjust the Java Build Path from the Properties of the project itself. A user commented that this step may not be necessary. We are on an older version of Eclipse due to our product, so YMMV, If needed (usually compile failures are the indicator), you then need to add, via the properties context menu on the project, the .jar files to the "Java Build Path" (you can do the same with a resources directory).

[image: Java Build Path]

This will allow you to properly build using the .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

For Compile time we need to add it to the Project runtime library.

For the run time you have to package the jar either in your EAR/WAR file or Load it to the Application server as a App server libraries.

Please let me know if you need further assistance on this.